# How to calculate an average value based on duplicate groups?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a table which contains data recorded at various times. The data *should* have been recorded at 5-minute intervals but this wasn't always the case.

Therefore, to try and clean this up:

- I set up a **Standard Time** column which contains fixed 5-minute intervals.
- The **Entered Time** column contains the times in which the data was recorded.
- The **Rounded Time** column contains the *Entered Time* rounded to its nearest 5 minute interval (formula from cell `C2`):

  ```
  =MROUND(B2, "0:05")
  ```
- The **Count** column contains the number of occurrences each *Rounded Time* appears (formula from cell `F2`):

  ```
  =COUNTIF($C$1:$C$19,C2)
  ```
- The **Duplicate/Unique** column is simply the *Count* column but represented with either "Duplicate" or "Unique" (formula from cell `G2`):

  ```
  =IF(F2>1, "Duplicate", "Unique")
  ```
- The **Average Data per Rounded Time** column is where I am having trouble as I want to average the data for each *Standard Time*. E.g. for `14/01/2014 12:40`, there are 2 duplicates, therefore I want to average the data from the *Data* column and insert this into cell  `H2`. In other words, `H2` would contain `23.18`. How could I achieve this?

[image: Table]

I have looked at possibly using the *Index/Match* combination but can't really grasp it.

Comment: You say *I want to average the data for each Standard Time*. The `Standard Time` column does not have any duplicates. Did you mean you want to average the data values for each set of duplicate `Rounded Time`?

Comment: @CharlieRB - My apologies, yes you are exactly right! Will edit the post, thank you for noticing that =)

Comment: Use `AVERAGEIF()`

Comment: @MátéJuhász - Thank you, indeed it did do the trick =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `AVERAGEIFS` function you can tell Excel to average data based on criteria being met.

Place this formula in `H2` and subsequent cells below.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(E:E,C:C,C2)
```

You will get an average of the data from column `E` on each line of column `H` based on the average of the duplicate values in the `Rounded Time` column.

[image]

Note: My Date/Time format may not be the same, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: +1, fantastic! Works great, thank you very much :)