# Values not available when using INDEX/MATCH functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Following on from my previous question: [How to calculate an average value based on duplicate groups?](https://superuser.com/questions/1051600/how-to-calculate-an-average-value-based-on-duplicate-groups)

I am trying to create a column *"Data for Standard Time"* which will contain values matching a certain time associated with the column *"Rounded Time"*. E.g. I want to match the time in `A2` with the same time in the `D` column and then get the data from the `I` column:

[image: Image of table]

The formula I use in `K2` is:

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$19,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$19,0))
```

But I receive an error and unfortunately, I cannot see why. I tested this by making sure all cells contained values but it made no difference.

[Attached a link to the file.](http://www.filedropper.com/example_1)

Comment: I could not duplicate the error. I used your formula and it worked for me. A common cause for errors is you can not match numbers to text. Make sure your data types are the same for your date/time information.

Comment: @CharlieRB - Thanks buddy for confirming this, I will check my dataset.

Comment: @CharlieRB - The data types for all columns used are `Type = 1` which should be numbers. I cannot see what else is wrong, I will try and upload this on a public server.

Comment: I'd like you to try something for me. Retype the data/time in both `A2` and `D2` exactly the same. Then recalculate the sheet. Does your formula work then? (FYI; we don't like to download files from questions for security reasons)

Comment: Placement of closing bracket is omitting 0 as last parameter. It should have been =INDEX($I$2:$I$19,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$19),0)

Comment: @CharlieRB - Thanks for your suggestion, I have created a new sheet and retyped the data/time manually. I still received the error using the same formula. However the comment by pat2015 helped and I've updated the question as there are still come inconsistencies.

Comment: @pat2015 - Your comment solved the issue. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INDEX takes three parameters. In the original formula the third parameter is missing.

Original   `=INDEX($I$2:$I$19,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$19,0))`

Since table has single column (I2:I19) , it should be 0 in this case. So the formula should have been

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$19,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$19),0)
```

Or

```
=INDEX($I$2:$I$19,MATCH(A2,$D$2:$D$19,1),0)
```

The third parameter in MATCH defaults to 1 when omitted and then it finds the largest value that is less than or equal to the lookup value. You can set it to 0 to find an exact match but there are no such exact matching values in your dataset.